# Windows Server 2012 R2: Client computers not showing in server dashboard

Tags: windows-server-essentials, essentials-2012-r2

We deployed a new Server 2012 Essentials and joined a client computer to the domain using CCW. This PC initially showed up in the Essentials Dashboard.

Later we joined a few more PCs to the domain and now found that these do not show up in the dashboard. Even the PC that was initially listed does no longer show up there. So something must have gone wrong during the process of configuring the server.

We found no way to get the PCs listed. They are listed in ActiveDirectory, however. A common suggestion we found using Google is to disconnect the computers and rejoin them using CCW. But I'm not happy with that solution so we did not try that. I don't like disconnecting the PCs from the domain because that will probably loose configuration and data already associated in the dashboard. And I'm not sure it will work because there's still the question: Why does the PC initially listed in dashboard no longer show up?

The main problem with this is that computers are no longer available through the RWW website and our customer wants to use this feature for remotely working on the office PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Just run http://server/Connect from the workstations. Don't take them out of the domain. You shouldn't lose any settings or data.